# Eshell can't find script on eshell path

Tags: emacs, eshell

**My goal**

I'm trying to add "/opt/bin" to the list of paths eshell uses to find scripts. So far I've tried to do this in three ways

**Attempts so far**

1) (setenv "PATH" (concat "/opt/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))

2) (eshell/addpath "/opt/bin:")

3) (add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/bin")

The first attempt does add "/opt/bin" to eshell's path (it shows up as the first instance of "/opt/bin:" in the output of calling "which lein" below)

The second attempt also adds "/opt/bin" to eshell's path (it shows up as the second instance of "/opt/bin:" in the output of calling "which lein" below)

I actually have had "/opt/bin" added to my exec-path for a while. I believe I did this so that /opt/bin would be on my path when running the term command to start a shell, this seems to work fine but doesn't help eshell find commands there.

**Failing attempts and temporary workaround**

You can see in the eshell output below that even though a command, lein, is available on the path eshell recognizes eshell doesn't find the command. However if I create a symbolic link from a directory that is in eshells default path to a script in /opt/bin eshell is then able to find it.

**Eshell output**

```
~ $ which lein
which: no lein in (/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/bin:)
~ $ l /opt/bin/ | grep lein
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin          kevin    12538 2019-01-17 07:32 lein
~ $ sudo ln -s /opt/bin/lein /usr/local/bin/lein
[sudo] password for kevin: 
~ $ 
~ $ which lein
/usr/local/bin/lein
```

I would prefer not to have to create symbolic links in /usr/local/bin/ just so that eshell can find scripts in my /opt/bin. Note even after restarting emacs it finds the symbolic link not the script in /opt/bin. This is occurring in a GUI instance of emacs-25 on linux mint debian (v9.3) edition.

**Question:**

How do I get eshell to actually check eshell path instead of the some default list of directories? Should I be updating a different path variable?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of `eshell/addpath`, it uses `setq` on `eshell-path-env`, which is a buffer local var.  This means that if you use `eshell/addpath`, it has to be executed in the context of each eshell buffer.  The best way to do this is to use a mode hook.

```
(defun jpk/eshell-mode-hook ()
  (eshell/addpath "/opt/bin"))
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook #'jpk/eshell-mode-hook)
```

I'm not super familiar with Eshell, so I'm not going to say this is the best way, but it should work.  `eshell-path-env` is set from `(getenv "PATH")` initially, so it's weird that setting `PATH` env var doesn't work (unless you're doing that after loading eshell).

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Assuming you are running emacs in a terminal emulator or tty; then you can just add `/opt/bin` to your `$PATH`. Eshell uses your `$PATH` to find external commands. Not sure how it works for GTK version.